# Qt add-in for VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I've installed qt add-in for VS2010 and when I try to "show" a path to Qt installed I'm getting an error that this ver of qt has been built with mingw. I get it, I've found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063467/how-do-i-set-up-qt-paths-in-visual-studio-2010)
but when I tried to type in console 'configure' I'm getting error that configure isn't recognized.
How shall I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the way Qt is built by MinGW and VS is different and has different files.

You have to download Qt source code. Click Start and search for Visual Studio 2008 command prompt or 2010 command prompt.

Go to Visual Studio Command prompt and navigate to Qt source code folder.
Type

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2008 --> if you have VS 2008
```

or use configure -platform win32-msvc2010 for VS 2010

and after that is done, just type

```
nmake
```

Wait until its built (4 hrs) and that should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Qt with VC it's best to have built Qt with visual studio.

See [How to build Qt for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010)

edit: Just unpack the sources, and from the visual studio command prompt do
`configure.exe -platform win32-msvc2010 -no-qt3support -fast`

Or you can just use the [vs2008 libs](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008), they will work with vs2010, you just can't mix Microsoft and gcc/mingw built libs.

Comment: I saw that, but as I've said, when I type 'configure' I'm getting an error

Comment: Then you either haven't installed the sources correctly or it's another error - have you checked the steps in the link?

Comment: @smallB: You need Perl installed & in your path in order for configure to work http://www.activestate.com/activeperl

Comment: @Grant Limberg - not anymore, Qt ships with a configure.exe

Comment: @Martin Beckett:  Last time I built Qt on Windows it had the configure.exe and still needed Perl

Comment: @Grant, just checked you now only need perl to build opensll from scratch http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC

Answer (score 1):

Follow this explanation:

[How to build Qt for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010)

And then everything will work (once you set up your Qt paths of course).